# Setup Universal Link - Can .well-known under subdirectory instead of root

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am exploring how to set-up a Universal link to an app. Hoping to jump right into my app when users enter the website. But due to business limitation, I can only create the .well-known directory that holds the apple-app-site-association json file under subdirectory like this:

https://localhost:8443/en/testing/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

From all of the tutorials I read online, it seems the .well-known directory must set up at the root directory of the domain but is it possible for me to create it in a subdirectory?

I have tried to setup a POC but seems Universal Links only works on https with non-self-signed ssl key. Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Universal link only works for directories and subdirectories present inside the apple-app-site-association file path.

If you have to keep the file inside the that directory only then you can manipulate .htaccess to take the reference of the file while retrieving the files from https.

Comment: How can we edit the `.htaccess` file to put the .well-known directory in a sub-directory?